# How to configure json element as optional in output json mapping in WSO2 DSS?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator

There is a option to configure the XML elements in XML ouput mapping as optional in WSO2 DSS, but I don't see any such option for json output mapping. Is there any way to make it as optional?